# Undefined index: HTTPS in /XXXXXX/page_job.php on line 71

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I installed `jobberbase` and everything went smoothly but I keep getting the error

`Undefined index: HTTPS in /XXXXXX/page_job.php on line 71` at the top of job post.

The code at line 71 are as follows;

```
        $current_url = (($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https" : "http").'://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

I just started learning php, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error, because you don't have *HTTPS* support, thus the *PHP* does not have such variable inside the `$_SERVER` system array.

To get rid of that error, just check if the `$_SERVER` actually has an *HTTPS* key/index item by using `isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])`. Change that line to be like this and check for the existence of the *HTTPS* key:

```
$current_url = ((isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https" : "http").'://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I change the code and its working like a charm.

Comment: @Abiel you are welcome. If you find my answer useful, then please mark it as accepted answer. To see how to accept an answer, please read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for this :)